# Getter should be a function but "getters.doubleCounter" is 20 - VUEX ERROR

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm learning about Vuex right now and I'm running into some trouble. While trying to create a `getter` on my vuex instance I'm getting this error when trying to render from one of my components:

> Getter should be a function but "getters.doubleCounter" is 20

#### store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    counter: 10
  },
  getters: {
    doubleCounter: state => {
      return state.counter * 2;
    }
  }
});
```

#### MY COMPONENT:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>This is a message from services</p>
    <button v-on:click="increment">+</button>
    <button v-on:click="decrement">-</button>
    {{ counter }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      counter() {
        return this.$store.getters.doubleCounter;
      },
    },
    methods: {
      increment: function () {
        this.$store.state.counter++
      },
      decrement: function () {
        this.$store.state.counter--
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Again when I try to render the page that this component is on. It fails while giving me the title error message in the console. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about your error but you shouldn't be manipulating the `state` directly in your `methods`. That's what [mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html) are for

Comment: Yea, I've been seeing that. I'll dig into that as well. Thanks.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. I suspect somewhere else not shown here, you are writing a value to `this.$store.state.doubleCounter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's causing your error but you are certainly not meant to be directly manipulating `state` outside of a *mutation*.

At no point should your code ever assign anything directly to a `state` property. For example, this is bad

```
this.$store.state.doubleCounter++
```

Here's what you should have.

```js
Vue.component('counter', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <p>This is a message from services</p>
    <button v-on:click="increment">+</button>
    <button v-on:click="decrement">-</button>
    {{ counter }}
  </div>
  `,
  computed: {
    counter() {
      return this.$store.getters.doubleCounter;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    increment: function () {
      this.$store.commit('increment')
    },
    decrement: function () {
      this.$store.commit('decrement')
    }
  }
})

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    counter: 10
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) { state.counter++ },
    decrement(state) { state.counter-- }
  },
  getters: {
    doubleCounter: state => {
      return state.counter * 2;
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app"><counter/></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
doubleCounter: (state) => {
      return state.counter * 2;
    }
```